# remove duplicate rows from mysql table (slightly complicated)

Tags: mysql

I'm hoping that there is a simple way in mysql to do the following.

Let's say that I have a table called **T1**

```
+-------+-------+-------------+
| gene1 | gene2 | correlation |
+-------+-------+-------------+
| ABC   | DEF   | 0.1         |
+-------+-------+-------------+
| DEF   | ABC   | 0.1         |
+-------+-------+-------------+
```

I want to delete entries where `gene1` and `gene2` are transposed and correlation is the same.

For instance, `IF (gene1 = 'ABC' AND gene2 = 'DEF' AND correlation = 0.1)` then I would like to remove these entries.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a query, simply do:

```
select t.*
from t
where gene1 < gene2
union all
select t.*
from t
where gene1 > gene2 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t.gene1 = t2.gene2 and t.gene2 = t2.gene1 and
                        t.correlation = t2.correlation
                 );
```

If you actually want to delete the entries, you can do:

```
delete t
    from t join
         t t2
         on t.gene1 = t2.gene2 and t.gene2 = t.gene1 and
            t2.correlation = t.correlation and
            t.gene1 > t.gene2;
```

The final condition (`>`) is so you only delete one of the rows that match.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the helpful suggestion. The select query works and returns the unique rows but the delete statement returns with zero rows affected. Any thoughts?

Comment: Think I found the issue. The line 'on t.gene1 = t2.gene2 and t.gene2 = t.gene1 and' should probably be 'on t.gene1 = t2.gene2 and t.gene2 = t2.gene1 and' instead

Comment: Ok, one small additional correction. 't.gene1 > t2.gene2; ' should probably be 't.gene1 > t.gene2; '. Now everything works as expected. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @J.Wadia . . . Yes.  Thank you.